# Access to user in django models

Tags: python, django, authentication

Hi i have problem with django python app. Im creating function in model in django - which gives me true or false in template.

Can i get access to logged user in function in model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view method (in views.py) should have a "request" parameter.  You can pass in the logged user like this:

```
class MyMethod(models.Model):
    def method(self, user):
        # do something with user
        return result    # true or false

def my_method(request):
    obj = MyModel.all().filter(...).get()
    result = obj.method(request.user)
    # pass "result" to template
```

If you have a list of objects and you want to pass in the user from the template, you need to put the user into a variable first:

```
def my_method(request):
    user = request.user
    objects = MyModel.all()
    # pass "user" and "objects" to template

(inside your template):
{% for obj in objects %}{{ obj.method.user||yesno:"yeah,no,maybe" }}{% endfor %}
```

This uses the [yesno](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno) tag on your true/false result.